# Linq to SQL - loading data in form then saving

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to do something that seems is straight forward, but need some help in identifying where I am going wrong when it comes to submitting the changes back.
The basic premise of this windows form is to query the database for a specific piece of info on form load then load it up for any changes that need to be made.

It loads up just fine and I double checked to make sure a primary key is there (which it is), but for some reason it will not save. The tkts.Log = Console.Out; doesn't even show anything when the save button is clicked.  I'm a beginner programmer and am trying out Linq to SQL so please offer pointers if something is way off.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TicketLogger;


namespace TicketLogger
{
    public partial class TicketInfo : Form
    {
        ITDataClassesDataContext tkts = new ITDataClassesDataContext();
        private Int32 ticket_id = 0;

        public TicketInfo(Int32 TicketID = 0)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Set local TicketID variable for use on load
            ticket_id = TicketID;
        }

        private void tBL_TICKET_HDRBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Save the new ticket to the database
            //I think the object Tickets contains the changes, not tkts, but how to access?
                try
                {
                    tkts.Log = Console.Out;
                    tkts.SubmitChanges();
                    tkts.Log.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception m)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(m.ToString());
                }
        }

        private void TicketInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tkts.Log = Console.Out;
            //Get the ticket ID and retrieve information
            var Ticket = from objTkts in tkts.TBL_TICKET_HDRs
                         where objTkts.TICKET_ID == ticket_id
                         select objTkts;
            this.tBL_TICKET_HDRBindingSource.DataSource = Ticket;
            tkts.Log.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to show the result of your LiNQ query in Console.Out?

Comment: If nothing's changing in the database I would suspect your databinding isn't setup properly - try binding with a plain old object and set a breakpoint in the Save method to verify. Also, you should be doing data loading/saving in a separate thread like: Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { codegoeshere });

Comment: Brian - Yes, in the try/catch block I am trying to see what is happening - it never shows anything so my guess is that it thinks there is nothing to update.  I wonder if it is an issue with the variant Ticket that is used on load, but I never access it when attempting to save.  Not sure if that is a valid point or not.

Comment: Chris - My code is what I have seen off of MSDN and other samples that I have found through my searches since i'm not a professional developer.  Can you describe further about binding with a plain object?

Comment: I found out why it will not update.  I was never passing any data to it.
I added this code in the try block before the submit changes and it took it.

                TBL_TICKET_HDR tkthdr = tkts.TBL_TICKET_HDRs.Single(t => t.TICKET_ID == ticket_id);
                tkthdr.ISSUE_DESC = iSSUE_DESCTextBox.Text;

For some reason, I just expected the code to "know" that the controls on the form is where it should go look.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it will not update.  I was never passing any data to it.
I added this code in the try block before the submit changes and it took it.

```
            TBL_TICKET_HDR tkthdr = tkts.TBL_TICKET_HDRs.Single(t => t.TICKET_ID == ticket_id);
            tkthdr.ISSUE_DESC = iSSUE_DESCTextBox.Text;
```

For some reason, I just expected the code to "know" that the controls on the form is where it should go look.